# React js change State in an instance of map() generated component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timer, this, setinterval

Question about React 16 from newbie.

React v16. I'm doing map() over tasks. Each task has its own timer component.

Parent:

```
render(props)
{
    return (
        this.props.tasks.tasks.map((task, id) = >
        {
            return (
                <div key={id} className="task" data-id={task.id}>
                    <div className="task-description">{ task.task }</div>
                    <Timer
                        onRemove={this.props.onRemove} 
                        whereToEdit={this.props.whereToEdit} 
                        id={task.id}       
                        handleTimer={this.handleTimer}
                    />
                    </div>
                )
            }
        )
    )
}
```

Each created timer has its own state with ms value.

When I start another timer or remove task, the previous timer component should call its own *Stop()* method.

Screenshot: 

[image]

Screenshot of This context for each generated instance: 

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vdEq.png]

I tried to control each instance from the parent and keep Milliseconds in the parent, but it starts all timers at the same time. Also I've tried to use *Mobx*, but I gave up since I'm not sure if I can do it with this pattern.

I need advice how to call method stop() inside of this Timer components

UPD: I finally solved this with refs. 
Task Id is generated by unique-html library, so in Parent I added this to

```
onRef={ref => (this[`example${task.id}`] = ref)}
```

and invoke this method in Parent from child:

```
start (thisId) {
        if (this.state.runningId !== thisId && this.state.runningId !== "") {
            this[`example${this.state.runningId}`].stop(thisId);
        } 
        this.setState({runningId: thisId});
}
```

But appeared new one - now when I start timer 3 and delete 2nd task - child state moves to next instance. So timer applies to wrong task after deleting.

Comment: your coding conventions show that you have quite messed up with react js code. Why you did not use `const tasks = this.props.tasks.tasks` just before `return`. You should try to make code as short and sweet as possible, Same goes with `const  isRunning = this.state.isRunning`. Make your code like a beautiful poetry.

Comment: oh, task props is useless for this child component. It was there by accident. Parent is task component itself.

Comment: I finally solved this problem with refs. But appeared new one - now when I start timer 3 and delete 2nd task - child state moves to next instance. So timer applies to wrong task after deleting

Comment: Rather than using `refs` I think I woudl rather save clocks in state with `Booleans` for each and have the running state to be `this.state.running.find(...do ur search)`. This case, whenever whichever button is clicked, you can modify the running of any of the clocks by just altering its respective state